# Problema com multi editor no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

Estou utilizando vários editores em um `custom post type`, porém o plugin `qTranslate` adiciona a abas de idiomas somente no editor default do Wordpress e nos demais não e junto com isso da um bug na aba que não possibilita alternar entre texto e visual.

[image: imagem]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Se você acredita ser um bug do plugin, talvez seja mais interessante reportar aos próprios desenvolvedores.

Comment: Eu entrei em contato com os desenvolvedores já, porém nenhuma resposta... No caso estou perguntando aqui mesmo porque vai que alguém já teve esse problema e arrumou alguma solução alternativa.

Comment: @DanielKoleski Se esse *custom post type* for específico de um tema ou plugin, não creio que haverá suporte *automático* para isso por parte do `qTranslate`. *Talvez* haja uma forma do tema ou plugin usar as funcionalidades do `qTranslate`, mas não não conheço a API do plugin para afirmar com certeza absoluta.

Comment: Então, eu que estou desenvolvendo o tema, mas não consegui resolver até agora, a solução que achei foi utilizar multi-site no wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

***É difícil; se não for impossível...***

Frequentei [o antigo fórum do qTranslate](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211151453/http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/) que o Qian Qin (o autor) tinha no site do plugin e nunca apareceu solução. Agora em 2014 não tenho certeza, mas antes disso nunca vi nada no [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Já abri os arquivos do plugin e tentei seguir a lógica por trás dessa funcionalidade; *só pra terminar fugindo em pânico:* é bem complicada de seguir. O plugin é muito antigo (2008) e apesar de ser mantido até hoje, acho que nunca passou por um *refactoring* para usar técnicas mais modernas. É totalmente procedural e só tem 14 hooks, entre `actions` e `filters`.

Enfim, minha sugestão é usar um `wp_editor` para cada língua e construir um *display* com jQuery-UI em *tabs*, cada *tab* contendo um editor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vez de usar um Meta Box, [um destes action hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036236/1287812) para imprimir sem o boxe. A referência de Estilo Administrativo é do plugin [WordPress Admin Style](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style). Em vez de imprimir os estilos, o mais indicado é fazer o *enqueue* do CSS completo.

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'post-new' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$hook.php", 'enqueue_sopt_10564' );

function enqueue_sopt_10564()
{
    // Run only for the types Posts and Movies
    global $typenow;
    if( !in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'movie' ) ) )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
}

add_action( 'edit_form_after_editor', 'imprimir_sopt_10564' );

function imprimir_sopt_10564( $post ) 
{
    if( !in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'post', 'movie' ) ) )
        return;

    /* IMPRIMINDO JS e CSS diretamente aqui, melhor fazer Enqueue */
    ?>
    <h3>Outro texto à traduzir</h2>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Português</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Español</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1"><?php echo wp_editor( 'Em pt_BR', 'ed_pt_br', array( 'textarea_name' => 'ed_pt_br', 'textarea_rows' => 10 ) ); ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-2"><?php echo wp_editor( 'In en_US', 'ed_en_us', array( 'textarea_name' => 'ed_en_us', 'textarea_rows' => 10 ) ); ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"><?php echo wp_editor( 'En es_ES', 'ed_es_es', array( 'textarea_name' => 'ed_es_es', 'textarea_rows' => 10 ) ); ?></div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {    
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>
        /* Component containers
        ----------------------------------*/
        .ui-widget { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
        .ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
        .ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
        .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; background: #ffffff; color: #333333; }
        .ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; color: #333333; font-weight: bold; background-color: #f1f1f1; background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9f9f9), to(#ececec)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); }
        .ui-widget-header a { color: #333333; }

        /* Interaction states
        ----------------------------------*/
        .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; background-color: #f1f1f1; background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9f9f9), to(#ececec)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ececec); font-weight: normal; color: #333333; }
        .ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; }
        .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #ececec; background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec, #f9f9f9); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec, #f9f9f9); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec, #f9f9f9); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ececec), to(#f9f9f9)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec, #f9f9f9); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ececec, #f9f9f9);  font-weight: normal; color: #000000; }
        .ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; background: #ffffff; font-weight: normal; color: #333333; }
        .ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; }
        .ui-widget :active { outline: none; }

        /* Interaction Cues
        ----------------------------------*/
        .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight  {border: 1px solid #e6db55; background: #ffffe0; color: #333333; }
        .ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a { color: #333333; }
        .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {border: 1px solid #cc0000; background: #ffebe8; color: #cc0000; }
        .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a { color: #cc0000; }
        .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text { color: #cc0000; }
        .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary { font-weight: bold; }
        .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary,  .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary { opacity: .7; filter:Alpha(Opacity=70); font-weight: normal; }
        .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled { opacity: .35; filter:Alpha(Opacity=35); background-image: none; }


        .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {background-image: url(../images/ui-icons_333333_256x240.png); }

        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-left-radius: 3px; }
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; }
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; }
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; }

        .ui-tabs { position: relative; padding: .2em; zoom: 1; } /* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { margin: 0; padding: .2em .2em 0; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; top: 1px; margin: 0 .2em 1px 0; border-bottom: 0 !important; padding: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 1px; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-processing a { cursor: text; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { cursor: pointer; } /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block; border-width: 0; padding: 1em 1.4em; background: none; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o plugin filtra o tipo de post que irá atuar. Em algum lugar por exemplo, "post  type == post" apenas. Se estiver ativo para páginas também "post type == pages" você deve ver as abas nelas também.

Dê uma fuçada dentro dos arquivos do plugin que com certeza você conseguirá habilitá-lo para custom-post-types( normalmente o nome do custom post type que você definiu).