# Como colocar Wordpress bilíngue?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, plugin

Precisei colocar um site (template desenvolvido por mim) sob CMS Wordpress em duas línguas, porém o plugin qTranslate não habilitava em minha versão.
Há alguma forma de fazê-lo sem plugins? Ou quem sabe um plugin que funcione na versão +3.8 ?

Comment: Resolvi o problema com o seguinte plugin: http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/

Answer (score 5):

Se o qTranslate ainda não foi atualizado, pode-se forçar sua compatibilidade trocando o seguinte valor no arquivo `plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate.php`:

```
define('QT_SUPPORTED_WP_VERSION', '3.8.1');
```

Além do qTrans, há três plugins principais para tradução:

- [WPML](http://wpml.org/): premium, cria um post/página espelho para cada tradução.
- [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/): freemium, trabalha com Multisite, um site para cada linguagem e interconexão entre posts/páginas traduzidos.
- [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/): grátis, nunca trabalhei nem analisei o funcionamento.

Também é possível criar uma solução caseira, como [neste exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10564/201).

Comment: como faz pra criar um gif como esse? http://i.stack.imgur.com/F7d5K.gif

Comment: Não achei nenhum utilitário pra Mac de captura de tela que exportasse direto pra gif, então usei um pra capturar vídeo (ScreenFlow) e depois outro especializado em criar gifs (Gif Brewery), depois exportei com 32 cores pra ficar leve mas com animação em boa qualidade.

Comment: Legal!...........